# Unable to access subpages in multisite NextJS+XM Cloud

Tags: multisite, nextjs, xm-cloud

So I have 2 sites under 1 project. My project was created by using https://github.com/sitecorelabs/xmcloud-foundation-head which already had multisite plugin installed and I'm able to setup the hostname in Site Groupping for relevant sites. So Site A will use content from Site A, and Site B will use content from Site B.
[image]

Situation: With this setup I'm only able to access to the homepage of each sites, If I access to subpages such as /login, /signup then I will get an error "**Page not found, the page does not exists. Go to the homepage**" Even though all the subpages was working before (if multisite is not enabled)
This is how I setup Site Identifier (I'm not sure whether its related or not)
[image]

This is how it declare my JSS_APP_NAME. I'm not sure its right format or not but I'm able to access to the homepage (with different content) of each sites. Also when I tried to making graphql query to the subpages, then I can see all the fields value and content template in the playground. So I guess the issue is more like configuration on Vercel and envinronment variable of it. But i'm still struggling to find the root cause of it. Thank you for all the supports
[image]

Comment: The new JSS SDK v21.6.0 released, where JSS_APP_NAME changed to  SITECORE_SITE_NAME. I will request you to compare your repo with https://github.com/sitecorelabs/xmcloud-foundation-head for upgrade